# How to add EditText data to database on Button click event?

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I am new to android programming. I have created a database in separate java class and I have an activity where I want some data, especially from EditText to be stored to database on button click. What am I doing wrong in the code? It doesn't start my savecount activity after I included the database code in OnClick event.

When the SaveClass activity starts, it freezes the app and eclipse shows the follow message: "Source Not Found" with an option to Edit Source Lookup Path.

Logcat shows following in recursion until launch gets timeout:

```
08-08 18:06:37.313: D/dalvikvm(1676): threadid=1: still suspended after undo (sc=1 dc=1)
08-08 18:06:37.323: I/dalvikvm(1676): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
08-08 18:06:37.793: I/Process(896): Sending signal. PID: 1676 SIG: 3
08-08 18:06:37.793: I/dalvikvm(1676): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
08-08 18:06:37.823: D/dalvikvm(1676): threadid=1: still suspended after undo (sc=1 dc=1)
08-08 18:06:37.823: I/dalvikvm(1676): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
08-08 18:06:38.042: W/ActivityManager(896): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
08-08 18:06:38.175: W/ActivityManager(896): Activity idle timeout for ActivityRecord{b4bf2e18 com.simple.tally.counter/.SaveCount}
```

**classdbOpenHelper**

```
package com.simple.tally.counter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;


public class classdbOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_COUNTED = "countedno";
    public static final String KEY_DESC = "countdesc";
    public static final String KEY_DATE = "countdate";

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME= "countdb";
    public static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "countable";
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;


    public classdbOpenHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE" + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" +
        KEY_ROWID + " INTEGET PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT " +
        KEY_COUNTED + " INTEGER " +
        KEY_DESC + " TEXT NOT NULL " +
        KEY_DATE + " TEXT NOT NULL);"
                ); 
    }


    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXITS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);

    }

}
```

**SaveCount.java**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.View;

public class SaveCount extends Activity {
TextView metersave;
classdbOpenHelper eventsData;
EditText desc;
Button Save;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_save_count);        
        Intent launchNewIntent = getIntent();
        String count = launchNewIntent.getStringExtra(SimpleTallyCounter.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
        metersave = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.metersave);
        metersave.setText(count); 
        final Button Save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Save);
        Save.setOnClickListener(new clicker());
        eventsData = new classdbOpenHelper(this);
        desc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.desc);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
      eventsData.close();
    }

    class clicker implements Button.OnClickListener {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String descvalue = desc.getText().toString();
            uSQLiteDatabase db = eventsData.getWritableDatabase();
            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
            cv.put(classdbOpenHelper.KEY_COUNTED, metersave.getText().toString());
            cv.put(classdbOpenHelper.KEY_DESC, descvalue);
            cv.put(classdbOpenHelper.KEY_DATE, System.currentTimeMillis());
            db.insert(classdbOpenHelper.DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: What happens when you press the button? What does logcat say? Does the app crash? Does blank data get inserted into your table? More information would be helpful to us.

Comment: where you are opening or closing database? see this example for all operations instert,delete or update http://blog.sptechnolab.com/2011/03/02/mysql/android-sqlite-insert-update-delete-and-display-data/

Comment: That clicker class is a bit weird. (Normally) You can just have your SaveCount class implement the onClickListener, and then inside the onClick method, test for v.getId() == R.id.Save, and then put that database saving code in there.

Comment: Oops, I updated the question with error and logcat info.

Comment: @imrankhan - I tried that method, but now when SaveCount activity starts, the app crashes and closes by itself.

Comment: @SanthoshSundar : post error log when app crashing

Answer (score 0):

like this `createComment`use this you store values in data base

```
   ed1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ed1);
   ed2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ed2);
   ed3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ed3);


  String str1 = ed1.getText().toString();
  String str2 = ed2.getText().toString();
  String str3 = ed3.getText().toString();
// stord data base values in database            
 comment = datasource.createComment(str1, str2 ,str3);
```

anr retreve database values `getAllAccounts`this in another activity

```
  AccountDataSource data = new AccountDataSource(getActivity());
    data.open();
    Accounts_list = data.getAllAccounts();
```

like see http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html it is use full.